# MSMQ Message Deserialization issue using C#

Tags: c#, msmq

The following source code will read message from the MSMQ queue in a plain text format. The expected message format  is ActiveXMessageFormatter

```
    string endPoint = @"myserver\monitorq"
    MessageQueue messageQ = new MessageQueue(endPoint);
    messageQ.Formatter = new ActiveXMessageFormatter();
    System.Messaging.Message MSMQmsg = messageQ.Receive();
    string body = messageQ.Formatter.Read(MSMQmsg).ToString();
```

If the input message format is different,  the below code is throwing an  exception

```
    string body = messageQ.Formatter.Read(MSMQmsg).ToString();
```

> Exception: Cannot deserialize the message passed as an argument.
>   Cannot recognize the serialization format.

I need to read the message from the MSMQ queue in a plain/ascii text format irrespective of the input message format type. My application will validate the message after reading from the queue.

Comment: If it were "plain" then you wouldn't be having this problem.  I suppose you'll want to guess at another format when ActiveXMessageFormatter.CanRead is *false*.

Comment: @HansPassant, The input message is coming from a different system, just in case if anything  wrong with the message/format, I need to send it to another queue. so I  have to read the message